# Property 'paramMap' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRoute'. /node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'ParamMap'

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

hero-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {  ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../services/hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() hero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private heroService: HeroService,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>     this.heroService.getHero(+params.get('id')))
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}

goBack(): void {
  this.location.back();
}

}
```

> Error: 1> node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'ParamMap'.
>
> 2>  Property 'paramMap' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRoute'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ParamMap` has been introduced in `4.0.0-rc.6` version. Make sure you have at-least Angular 4 version.

Comment: What is the angular 2 equivalent?

Comment: @Ring why you want go backward version??

Answer (score 2):

IN the latest version of angular i.e 2.4.10 to get the **ID** you can simply use

**const  id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];**

Comment: Now best practice is :  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be angular version conflict.your version may be lower version than 4.0.0-rc.6
This method may be help to resolve yore issue

add bellow line to the parameter send component:

**this.router.navigate(['profile'],{queryParams:{authdata:email}});**

add bellow line to the parameter  receive component:

**this.route.snapshot.queryParams['authdata'];**

bellow line to the Routermodule:
    **{ 
      path:'profile',
      component: ProfileComponent
    }**

Answer (score 0):

On latest version you can now write :

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
//...
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
//...
ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) {
        console.log ('id parameter: ', id);
    } else {
          console.log ('no id parameter');
    }
}
```

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Angular tutorial and needed to **change this code in hero-detail.component.ts**:

```
getHero(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHero(id)
        .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```

to this one:

```
getHero(): void {
    const id= +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.heroService.getHero(id)
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```